# Virtual camera from panorama

Tags: camera, camera-calibration, camera-pose, homography

I'm trying to virtualize a camera from a panorama.

That is, suppose I have a really big picture, for example: a soccer field.

Then I want to simulate a camera that focuses on certain regions of the game.

My initial idea was to use the essential matrix to carry out this task.

Ideally, it would be simply to calculate a homography but as the calculation using only the parameters of the virtual camera?